# How to use same power BI dashboard for other client

Tags: powerbi

We have two same clients and have the same structure of data. My Question is that How we can use the same dashboard for these clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create row level security.so dashboard remain same . but data shown is as per client login user .